# Displaying Thymeleaf model list with conditions

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I want to display the list of model attribute.but i am getting error like

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: `"(${storeInfo.storeStatus} == 'InActive')? (color:red):(color:black)""`

below is the code,Please help in this

```
<select id="storeDropDown" th:field="*{storeId}" name="storeId" class="form-control input-md mb-md">
<option value="NA" th:name="stareStatus" th:text="#{reports.selectStore}"> 
</option>
<option th:each="storeInfo : ${storeInfoList}"  th:value="${storeInfo.storeId}"  th:style="(${storeInfo.storeStatus} == 'InActive'||'Active')? (color:red):(color:black)" th:text="${storeInfo.storeName}" th:name="${storeInfo.storeStatus}"></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expressions just don't make sense to me (you have extra parens, quotes and are trying to `OR` a boolean and a string).  If I had to guess, maybe this?

```
th:style="${storeInfo.storeStatus == 'InActive' ? 'color: red;' : 'color: black;'}"
```